# Count string field in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I want to count the string field if it matches regex.

**Ex:**

```
"mappings": {
    "test": {
        "properties": {
            "id1": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "payload": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "id2": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "timestamp": {
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Count only if payload matches **[a-zA-Z]***

I want to create a table with the field, so where exactly should I add a query or a script?